# Javascript compare 2 arrays index by index, and not by total number of values the 2 arrays have in common

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, iterator

So i have this code that returns the result of comparing 2 arrays. the function compares how many values the two arrays have in common and then outputs the percentage of values that are in common.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 1];
const array2 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 6];

const compareThem = (num1, num2) => {
  let finalArray = [];
  num1.forEach((e1) => num2.forEach((e2) => {
    if (e1 === e2) {
      finalArray.push(e1)
    }
  }))
  const divideThem = Math.floor((finalArray.length / num1.length) * 100)
  const toPercent = (divideThem.toFixed(1) + '%')
  return toPercent;

};
console.log(compareThem(array1, array2))
```

But i would like to do something different. I would like to go index by index and have the code say does array1[0] === array2[0], [1] === [1] and so on. I am not looking for total number of values in common rather total number of indices they have in common. I dont want the code to say array1[1] === array2[3].
What would be the best approach to this problem? I am thinking first off i will have to use something other than foreach?

Comment: The `forEach` callback function gets a second argument that's the array index. You can use that to compare with the same index in the other array.

Comment: This is a very curious question, because what you want to do is actually much easier than the above code.

Comment: @Barmar but wouldn’t that just return how many indexes they have in common? As opposed to comparing the values at the index. So saying array1[1] = 5 and array2[1] also = 5

Comment: Also, what would your expected output look like? You've mentioned what you don't want it to be but haven't said what result you're actually after. Are you after an array of booleans: `[true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false]` ?

Comment: @NickParsons I want it to return an array of the values that were in common. That way the length of final array can be divided by length of array1 to return a decimal which is converted to percent and that percent will be how many of the indexes had the same value

Comment: You don't compare the indexes, you compare the elements at the index: `e1 == num2[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare `e1` with the element in the other array with the same index. All the array iteration functions pass the index as an argument to the callback.

If you just need the count, there's no need to push into an array. You can use `reduce()` to total the number that match.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 1];
const array2 = [1, 3, 6, 7, 6];

const compareThem = (num1, num2) => {
  let counter = num1.reduce((total, e1, index) => e1 === num2[index] ? total + 1: total, 0)
  const divideThem = Math.floor((counter / num1.length) * 100)
  const toPercent = (divideThem.toFixed(1) + '%')
  return toPercent;

};
console.log(compareThem(array1, array2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function received a second argument which is the index. You can use that index to compare the value the the value of the second array.

The end result would look something like this

```
const compareThem = (a1, a2) => {
  let commonIndices = [];
  a1.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element === a2[i]) {
      commonIndices.push(element)
    }
  });
  return commonIndices;
};
```